# Apache giraph process graph with a custom algorithm

Tags: apache, graph, frameworks, jar, dependencies

I have a custom algorithm for processing a graph which accepts a txt file as input. Because it is a large scale graph I want to implement it in the apache giraph framework. I' ve done a lot of research but I am still not sure if I am in the right path.

I am reading a .csv file which contain the graph data and using a parser I am converting it to the txt file and uploading to the HDFS file system of hadoop.

I have read the SimpleShortestPathsVertex example from the apache quick start guide and I can see that processes the data from a file in HDFS using the jar-with-dependencies jar file.

My problem is that I haven't yet understood how can I add my algorithm in the apache giraph framework and start the process of the graph. Can I add my algorithm to apache framework using eclipse and modify it from there or there is any other way?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look here:
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/GIRAPH/Shortest+Paths+Example

Where you able to run this example?
If yes.
Familiarize yourself with the different Writable formats of hadoop! Else it is hard to use these to your algorithm.

All computation concerning the graph is done in the compute() function. 
(If you're more advanced have a look into the workerContext preSuperstep and Aggregators!)
You can change the example, but as soon as you use other data types you have to change your VertexReader and VertexWriter.

If you have a specific Algorithm in mind, make up your mind what you need for the computation and specify the layout of your input file. Then adapt your VertexReader and -Writer. And then finaly start the implement your compute() function!

Of course you can use eclipse! Simply Reference the Giraph jar (For me it is "giraph-0.1-jar-with-dependencies.jar") And start coding. 
All you need is a instance of these files specific to your algorithm:

- YourGiraphJob    (the file starting the Hadoop/Giraph job)
- YourVertex       (Specifies your compute() function executed on each Vertex)
- YourInputFormat  (Specifying the Writable formats of YourReader)
- YourOutputFormat (Specifying the Writable formats of YourWriter)
- YourReader       (Specifies how your inputFile is transformed e.g. that for each line a Vertex can be initialized using given information)
- YourWriter       (Specifies how your outputFile is generated from the vertices)

(optionaly a WorkerContext if you want to use Aggregators.)

Simply checkout: http://giraph.apache.org/source-repository.html 
using eclipse and you should have the code including an example application you can toy around with!